# UILabel not displaying after iOS 8.0 upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just updated to iOS 8.0 this morning. I have a piece of code which created some labels and displays them on the scree next to some images. It was working fine before the update. Now the label and the image is not displaying. Can some one please help as I have tried everything I can think of and nothing has solved my issue and couldn't find anyone else with a similar issue. Code attached below.

```
UIView *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, kCategoryLabelHieght)];
labelView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"2D2D2D"];

UILabel *categoryTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 200, kCategoryLabelHieght)];
categoryTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
categoryTitle.text = text;
categoryTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];

codeAppDelegate *appDelegate = (codeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *fetchedCategory = [appDelegate getCategoryByName:text];

UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 20, 20)];

if(fetchedCategory.count)
{
    for (int t=0; t<fetchedCategory.count; t++) {
        Dealcategory_List *catList = [fetchedCategory objectAtIndex:t];
        NSString *titleImage = [self URLEncodeString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",catList.image]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:titleImage];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *imgTabs = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        //        [header2 setImage:imgTabs forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imgTabs resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 10, 2, 0) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile];

        img.image= imgTabs;
    }
}
else
{
    NSArray *fetchedNewsCategory = [appDelegate getNewsCategoryByName:text];

    if(fetchedNewsCategory.count > 0)
    {
        for (int t=0; t<fetchedNewsCategory.count; t++) {
            News_Categories *catList = [fetchedNewsCategory objectAtIndex:t];
            NSString *titleImage = [self URLEncodeString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",catList.category_image]];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:titleImage];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *imgTabs = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            //        [header2 setImage:imgTabs forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imgTabs resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 2, 0) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile];

            img.image= imgTabs;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *fetchedCompetition = [appDelegate getCompetitionByName:text];

        if(fetchedCompetition.count > 0)
        {
            for (int t=0; t<fetchedCompetition.count; t++) {
                Competitions_List *catList = [fetchedCompetition objectAtIndex:t];
                NSString *titleImage = [self URLEncodeString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",catList.competition_tab_image]];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:titleImage];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *imgTabs = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                //        [header2 setImage:imgTabs forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imgTabs resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 2, 0) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile];

                img.image= imgTabs;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

categoryTitle.textColor = color;
[labelView addSubview:img];
[labelView addSubview:categoryTitle];

[self.contentView addSubview:labelView];
```

Comment: In scanning your code, I see several things that don't make any sense to me. A) You're going through your `Categories or NewsCategories or Competitions` and assigning each of those images to your imageview, replacing any previous one. Thus the only image to be displayed will be the last one? B) You're calling `resizableImageWithCapInsets` and throwing away the results? C) is p4sh4's point: why create a labelView to assign other views to? Either create a plain `UIView` or just add the two views directly to the `contentView`?

Comment: `Just updated to iOS 8.0 this morning.` Then the next thing you should do is updating to 8.0.2 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, kCategoryLabelHieght)];
```

You are defining a `UIView` but allocating a `UILabel`. iOS 8 is less tolerant to errors like this. Try to change it to

```
UIView *labelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, kCategoryLabelHieght)];
```

Comment: This sounds weird to me. Maybe not in IB, but in code you should certainly be able to add a subview to `UILabel`.

Comment: Hm, you are correct, I just tried to do it and succeeded. I had a problem with the labels defined in IB - I had a UIView attached to a UILabel subclass by mistake, it worked in iOS 7 but stopped in iOS 8. Then not really what the op's problem could be.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you for your help :)